# jQuery selector, get elements with no class type A and no ancestors have class type A

Tags: jquery

I need a custom selector which grabs all LI's who do not have the class hiddenField and who have no ancestors with the class hiddenField

E.G

```
var lis= $f.find('li:not(.hiddenField)').filter('andAncestorsHaveNoClassHiddenField)
```

Bit stretched for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$f.find("li:not('.hiddenField')").filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parents().hasClass(".hiddenField"); 
})
```

Comment: No. But didn't you test before accepting? Set up a jsFiddle or something, and we'll get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, got rid of the "." and getting closer, its working now, just need to fix my erroneous code :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$f.find('li:not(.hiddenField) :not(.hiddenField)').parent()
```